# How to add "and" to a comma separated string

Tags: groovy

If I have a string like `"one, two, three"` what is a way to convert it to `"one, two, and three"`

If the string contains only one item then no `and` is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to handle cases where there are either 1, 2, 3+ words:

```
def doIt(string) {
    def elements = string.split(', ')

    switch(elements.size()) {
        case 0:
            ''
            break
        case 1: 
            elements[0]
            break
        case 2:
            elements.join(" and ")
            break
        default:
            new StringBuilder().with {
                append elements.take(Math.max(elements.size() - 1, 1)).join(', ')
                append ", and "
                append elements.last()
            }.toString()
            break
    }
}

assert doIt("one, two, three, four") == "one, two, three, and four"
assert doIt("one, two, three") == "one, two, and three"
assert doIt("one, two") == "one and two"
assert doIt("one") == "one"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
def fun(s) {
  def words = s.split(', ')
  words.size() == 1 ? words.head() : words.init().join(', ') + ', and ' + words.last()
}

assert fun("one, two, three") == "one, two, and three"
assert fun("one") == "one"
```

​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: or `def arr = s.tokenize(/,/); arr.size() > 1 ? (arr.init() + (' and' + arr.last())).join(/,/) : s` :)

Comment: or `input.reverse().replaceFirst(',', ', and'.reverse()).reverse()` ;-)

Comment: Or indeed: `input.replaceAll(/(,)(?!.*,)/, ', and')` (if you like your regular expressions unreadable) ;-)